# Clear:both before the end of the block

Tags: css, css-float

So often, I we wind up doing something like this:

```
<div class="one">
   <div class="floating-two">content</div>
   <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

What we usually mean is, "make sure that any floated elements are included into block one".  Sof potentially, any background applied to "one" appears behind everything, floating or not.

I am looking for a cleaner way to do this.  After all, the "clear" div is simply a style that we intend to apply to "one".  We could do:

```
.floating-two:after{
  clear:both;
}
```

But this is not correct either.  Floating-two doesn't know whether there might be other blocks following it before "one"'s closure.

Has anyone developed a trick for this one?

Comment: Clearing floats is a pain. it's one of the reasons I find myself using `display:inline-block` for layout more than floats these days.

Comment: I just wrote an explanation on this problem, view this for a demo: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9559659/inner-div-arent-pushing-other-div-cant-get-clear-both-to-work/9560062#9560062

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `overflow: hidden` on the outer div and it will stretch to the height needed to contain `.floating-two`. Example fiddled here: http://jsfiddle.net/neilheinrich/rBBMp/6/

```
.one {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: thanks, especially for the working example.  I saw overflow:hidden used all over the place, but the stretching behavior was never clear to me.  I always thought, it was used to clip the extra space...

Answer (score 8):

You can clear do this in two ways without adding markup (without a `<div class="clear"..>` or equiv):

```
.one:after {
   content: ".";
   display: block;
   clear: both;
   visibility: hidden;
   height: 0;
}
```

OR

```
.one {
    overflow: hidden
}
```

Comment: There is no need to put a dot in the content. `content: "";` will also work

Answer (score 1):

EDIT

I do believe that RobW is correct in saying you can't do this with :after, but you can make it more dynamic with this css:

http://jsfiddle.net/qQaQg/2

```
.one :last-child
{
  clear:both;
}
```

Comment: @RobW I believe you are correct in asserting it is incorrect, however I don't believe your test illustrates that.  I believe this one does: http://jsfiddle.net/qQaQg/

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, the background should include the second DIV, which is not the case.

Comment: @RobW I added a fixed width and height because while building it I only had the floating element.  This made it show no background.  I've updated the demo.  Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add a real element with the `clear` property. If you don't like the divs, use a `<br>`. It's the shortest, valid element which doesn't modify the lay-out:

```
<br class="clear" />
```

Comment: Just as a little note here, RobW should receive credit for this because he pointed out that you need an element to clear the float.

Comment: @Joseph Your idea works in some cases, which is also great ;) About "need an element", see this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qQaQg/3/

Comment: This isn't an elegant solution and is specifically what I was trying to get around. If I were to change the styles of underlying elements, the "clear" element may become unnecessary, or downright harmful. I am looking for ways to separate style information from content - and this violates that division.